# JTable does not render

Tags: java, swing, jtable, japplet

When page with applet is loaded JTable object's content is rendered perfectly. When I close a tab and reopen it content set at start is rendered, but when the content I changed via `setValeAt()` table becomes empty. When i remove all html tags from data model everything works. I do nothing with table's default renderer only implent data model. All values are set via `setValeAt()` and it works (i checked it).
Can someone have any idea what could be wrong?

Here is sample code wich reproduces the error. Run the applet (values will be changing) and then close the tab (NOT browser) and reopen it. I tested it in Firefox 3.6.13 and Java 1.6.0_22-b04 on Linux and Windows XP. It acts the same.

```
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

public class test extends JApplet 
{
    class model extends AbstractTableModel
    {

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() 
        {
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() 
        {
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int arg0, int arg1) 
        {
            return "<html><b>" + Math.random() + "</b></html>"; // does not work
            //return "" +  Math.random(); // work
        }

        public void setValueAt(Object newValue, int row, int col)
        {
            fireTableCellUpdated(row, col );
        }
    }

    JTable t = new JTable();

    public void init()
    {
        t.setModel( new model() );
        add( t );
    }

    public void start()
    {
        new Thread( new Runnable() 
        {

            @Override
            public void run() 
            {
                int i=0;
                try 
                {
                    while( ++i<100 )
                    {
                        Thread.sleep(100); // thanks to camickr
                        t.setValueAt(Void.class, (int)(Math.random()*10) %3, (int)(Math.random()*10) %3 );
                    }

                }
                catch (InterruptedException e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

HTML applet code inside `index.html`

```
<applet width="500px" height="500px" alt="test test test" code="test.class">
</applet>
```

Compilation code:
`javac test.java`

produces: files `test$1.class  test.class  test$model.class`

Running first time OK. Make new tab and then close applet tab. Reopen applet tab (do not close browser) and table content does not render.

**EDIT 2**
**IT IS A JVM BUG! see https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6995386 and others related. It only affects JRE 1.6.0_22**

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't reproduce the problem using JDK6_7 on XP.

> values will be changing

The values don't keep changing since you don't sleep after each update to the model. I changed the code slightly:

```
// Thread.sleep(100);

while( ++i<100 )
{
    t.setValueAt(Void.class, (int)(Math.random()*10) %3, (int)(Math.random()*10) %3 );
    Thread.sleep(500);
}
```

Comment: You are right, my mistake. Do you confirm this strange behaviour?